# How can I enforce the evaluation of \refstepcounter when called?

Tags: counters

I have an issue with `\themycounter` being evaluated too late:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\defineXX}[3]{%
  \refstepcounter{mycounter} 
  \expandafter\def\csname#1@id\endcsname{FSR \themycounter}
  \expandafter\def\csname#1@definition\endcsname{#2}
  \expandafter\def\csname#1@misc\endcsname{#3}
}

\newcommand{\printXX}[2]{%
  \hypertarget{#1}{%
  \subsection{\csname#1@id\endcsname}\label{#1}}

  \csname#1@definition\endcsname
    
  Test: \csname#1@misc\endcsname

  #2
}


\begin{document}

\defineXX{test-1}{Definition 1}{Bla bla}
\defineXX{test-2}{Definition 2}{Bla bla}

\printXX{test-1}{Additional remark 1}
\printXX{test-2}{Additional remark 2}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image: The counter is set to 2 in both items]

but I want to see `FSR 1` and `FSR 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand `\themycounter` before storing it. Here's one way, using the age-old `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup...}\x` expansion technique:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defineXX}[3]{%
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\@namedef{#1@id}{FSR \themycounter}}\x
  \@namedef{#1@definition}{#2}
  \@namedef{#1@misc}{#3}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\printXX}[2]{%
  \hypertarget{#1}{%
  \subsection{\csname#1@id\endcsname}\label{#1}}

  \csname#1@definition\endcsname
    
  Test: \csname#1@misc\endcsname

  #2
}


\begin{document}

\defineXX{test-1}{Definition 1}{Bla bla}
\defineXX{test-2}{Definition 2}{Bla bla}

\printXX{test-1}{Additional remark 1}
\printXX{test-2}{Additional remark 2}

\end{document}
```

`\@namedef{<cmd name>}{<stuff>}` (from the kernel) was just a convenience/shorter alternative to `\expandafter\def\csname <cmd name>\endcsname{<stuff>}`.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. In the production code I obtain `! You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode. \@->\spacefactor \@m {}`

Comment: @MarkusW.: Note the addition of a [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) pair.

Comment: Ahh, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `\edef` instead of `\def`. On the other hand, `\refstepcounter` does nothing more than `\stepcounter`, because it is performed at `\defineXX` and when you use `\label` it's too late.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\defineXX}[3]{%
  \stepcounter{mycounter}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname#1@id\endcsname{FSR \themycounter}%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1@definition\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1@misc\endcsname{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\printXX}[2]{%
  \hypertarget{#1}{%
  \subsection{\csname#1@id\endcsname}\label{#1}}%
  \csname#1@definition\endcsname

  Test: \csname#1@misc\endcsname

  #2
}


\begin{document}

\defineXX{test-1}{Definition 1}{Bla bla}
\defineXX{test-2}{Definition 2}{Bla bla}

\printXX{test-1}{Additional remark 1}
\printXX{test-2}{Additional remark 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]